# Virtualize GridView inside ScrollViewer in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-store-apps, virtualization, scrollviewer

I have the following application:

I am developing a Windows Store app in which I need to show a big grid filled with buttons. The content of the buttons are some numbers and when I click any of them, I open a Popup with editor, where I edit those numbers. For that purpose I use a GridView, I put an ItemsWrapGrid as ItemsPanel. This makes the grid look exactly as I need it to look. I put the GridView inside a ScrollViewer, because I need to scroll the grid in both directions, since it has a lot of elements. Also I need to have the pinch-to-zoom effect that the ScrollViewer gives out of the box. I need to change the ItemsSource for that GridView when the user chooses different source in a ListView next to the GridView.

The problem:
Putting the GridView inside the ScrollViewer breaks the Virtualization inside and this has a major impact on my performance. When I switch the ItemsSource of the GridView, it takes more than 3-4 seconds for the rendering and during that time, the UI is frozen.

My question:
How can I keep the awesome stuff that the ScrollViewer gives me and also keep the virtualization? Because when I remove the ScrollViewer, changing between the ItemsSources happens almost instantly.

Any idea?

Comment: I know I am late, but did you ever find/implement a solution that you could put here as an answer to yourself? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, sorry. The project died and I stopped looking for a solution. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best off implementing virtualization yourself since you're trying to use the `GridView` far from the use cases it was designed for.

Put a `Canvas` in a `ScrollViewer` that does both pan and zoom and handle view change events on the `ScrollViewer` by laying out item containers inside and around the viewport. Avoid unnecessary changes too, so keep containers in place if they are to stay realized between view change events and recycle containers that are leaving the viewport neighborhood.

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing my own virtualization, but that seemed like an overkill for the situation. My experience with custom virtualization scenarios shows that there is a ton of cases that you can screw up.

Comment: What I am now trying to do is make a copy of the template of the GridView. It has an internal ScrollViewer, which I am trying to take advantage of. When I set all the needed parameters there, the virtualization still seems to work, which is nice. But now I can't break off the ItemsWrapGrid at the element count that I want. It always goes to the next row just before it goes out the viewport. I am guessing some internal code does that in order to keep the virtualization working.

Comment: Like I said - it wasn't designed for your use case so sooner or later you'll hit a brick wall. I'd recommend either rolling your own virtualization or changing the design.